# xmlEventParse (package XML) messes up encoding

Tags: xml, r, character-encoding

I am having a hard time to read in a XML file with german umlauts (ä, ü, ö) and other special characters. The weird thing is that R manages to read in the file correctly when just using 'readLines()'. However, as soon as the xmlEventParse part of the function 'get.all.text()' finishes building up 'collected.text' with the help of the handler functions 'sE2()', 'eE2()' and 'tS2', all special characters are broken. It appears that even breaks are inserted before each of these characters.

The XML file says '?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?' in the first line. Hoever, I thought that shouldn't be a problem because the 'readLines()' function reads in the text properly.

Do you guys have any pointers for me how to proceed?

Thanks!

```
get.all.text <- function (file) {
  read.file <- paste(readLines(file), collapse = " ")
  assign("collected.text", c(), env = .GlobalEnv)
  assign("get.text", F, env = .GlobalEnv)
  xmlEventParse(read.file, asText = T, list(startElement = sE2,
                                            endElement = eE2,
                                            text = tS2),
                error = function (...) { },
                saxVersion = 1)
  head(collected.text)
}

sE2 <- function (name, attrs) {
  if (name == "s") {
    get.text <<- T }
}

eE2 <- function (name, attrs) {
  if (name == "s") {
    get.text <<- F
  }
}

tS2 <- function (content, ...) {
  if (get.text & nchar(content) > 0) {
    collected.text <<- c(collected.text, content)
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not to use `xmlParse(...,encoding='UTF-8')` ?

Comment: That would work. However, I have to use the xmlEventParse because the files I'm working on are very large.

Comment: you will need to manually change the encoding in your xml header. The encoding attribuite in `xmlParse` is ignored if the xml file itself states the encoding to be used. This is detailed in `?xmlParse'

Comment: `xmlEventParse` does not have as encoding attribute. Also, if I change the XML header, nothing changes. However, if I first establish a file connection with `file(<filename>, encoding = "ascii"`, something changes (no breaks at special characters but other substitutes for the special characters).